# Passing through properties when wrapping an Ember component

Tags: ember.js

When wrapping an Ember component, how do I allow passing through a property while falling back to the inner component's default when omitting that property?

For example, take `basic-input` which gets wrapped by `super-input`:

**components/basic-input.js**

```
export default Component.extend({
  placeholder: "foo"
});
```

**templates/components/basic-input.hbs**

```
{{ input placeholder=placeholder }}
```

**components/super-input.js**

```
export default Component.extend({});
```

**templates/components/super-input.hbs**

```
<label>
  <span>{{label}}</span>
  {{ basic-input placeholder=placeholder }}
</label>
```

Passing `placeholder` to `super-input` works

```
{{super-input label="baz" placeholder="bar"}}
```

but how do we allow `basic-input`'s default value of `foo` to be used when the property is omitted?

```
{{super-input label="baz"}}
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e8w0brgb/

Comment: `basic-input` component should implement the required feature(ie., if placeholder is undefined then use default value). for that you can use what alptugd is suggested or `{{input placeholder=(if placeholder placeholder 'foo') }}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is where the computed property comes into play. You can define a computed property within the inner component and pass in value as a different property from the parent component. What I mean is sth. as follows:

```
  placeholderInternal: Ember.computed('placeholder', function() {
    // return the value passed from parent component if exists; return the default value otherwise
    return this.get('placeholder') || 'foo';
  })
```

then you will use this computed property as the placeholder within the template. Please check the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/a8de5301e29f829ff5943181b371681e?openFiles=components.basic-input.js%2Ctemplates.components.super-input.hbs) to see what I wrote in action. Ember is quite powerful in terms of computed property feature; I prefer to rely on them whenever I can. By the way you also need to pass the `placeholder` property to `basic-input` within `super-input.hbs`. This is what I had already done in the twiddle.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm hoping there's a way to accomplish this which doesn't involve altering the inner component, as (a) ideally inner components don't know they're inner components and (b) sometimes the inner component is a 3rd-party library.

Comment: if this is what you want; you must define the computed property I have mentioned within the `super-component` and pass it to `inner-component`. would you like me to modify the twiddle?